# Next.js 13 images and videos not showing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jsx, tsx

This my code for the a components inside my Next.js 13 with ts, eslint, as well as Chakra UI.

Both images and videos is not working or showing.

I tried the HTML `<img>` tag as well as importing Image from Chakra. Still the same issue it's not working.

```
import { Flex } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import Image from 'next/image';

const Navbar:React.FC = () => {
    
    return (
        <>
        <Flex bg="white" height="44px" padding="6px 12px">
            <Flex>
                <Image 
                src={"/public/images/logo.png"} alt='Apex Logo' width="350" height="300"/> 
            </Flex>
        </Flex>
        <video src={'/public/images/about video.mp4 '} controls height="100%" width="100%"></video>
        </>
    )
}
export default Navbar;
```

[image: screenshot for whats rendering in the next server]

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont have to pass `/public`

```
src={"/images/logo.png"}
```

next.js automatically will go inside `public` folder